# What does 'in a rhythmic fashion' mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I have the following sentence:

> What this program does is produces fluorescent proteins **in a rhythmic fashion** and generates a small molecule that allows bacteria to communicate and synchronize, as you're seeing in this movie.

What does 'in a rhythmic fashion' mean?

The [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fashion) gives the following definitions for *fashion*:

> **fashion noun** (POPULAR STYLE)
>
> A2 [C or U]: a ​style that is ​popular at a ​particular ​time, ​especially in ​clothes, ​hair, ​make-up, etc.:
>
> - Long ​hair is back in fashion for men.
> - Fur ​coats have gone out of fashion.
> - a ​programme with ​features on ​sport and fashion
> - She always ​wears the ​latest fashions.
>
> **fashion noun** (MANNER)
>    › [S] a way of doing things:
>   - The ​rebel ​army ​behaved in a ​brutal fashion.

It is not clear how either of these definitions applies to the current usage. Or if one of them doesn't, it's not clear why it is *that* one that does!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The word [fashion](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/fashion) in this context means "A manner of doing something" and is used as synonym of the words manner, way, method, mode, style; system, approach.

Some example sentences in this sense:

> The work is done in a rather casual fashion
>
> I think that danger may lurk in the background, but it is likely to
>   arise in an indirect fashion, rather than directly.

The word [rhythmic](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/rhythmic) means "occurring regularly".

Example sentence for the word rhythmic is:

> There are rhythmic changes in our bodies

So ***in a rhythmic fashion*** means "in a regular way or system".